# Lightbox without icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I want use lightbox and I did it but doesn't work. 
I tried everything. Good version, script on the end body tag etc.
Include: lightbox.css, lightbox.js, jquery-1.7.2.js
I don't see icon but I see that they are there.
When I have lightbox.js after jquery in head section it still doesn't work.
I have good paths I think.

```
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl" lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
    <meta name="Description" content="blablabla" />
    <meta name="Keywords" content="blablabla" />
    <title>blablabla</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexStyle.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="banner.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="zmienslajd();">
<div class="backgroundContainer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="upContainer">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="blablabla"><img src="models/logo.png" alt="Przepraszamy - awaria logo." /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <ol>
                    <li><a href="blablabla2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Oferta</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blablabla3">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blablabla4"></a></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
        <div id="banner">

        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
        <div class="midContainer">
            <a href="Models/galeria1.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="Models/mingaleria1.jpg" alt="Zdjęcie 1"></a>
            <a href="Models/galeria2.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="models/mingaleria2.jpg" alt="Zdjęcie 2"></a>
            <a href="Models/galeria3.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="models/mingaleria3.jpg" alt="Zdjęcie 3"></a>
            <a href="Models/galeria4.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img src="models/mingaleria4.jpg" alt="Zdjęcie 4"></a>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox.js"></script>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
        <div class="botContainer">
            Time4Fruit.pl &copy; 2016 by blablabla
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> My css:

```
/* Preload images */
body:after {
  content: url("images/close.png") url("images/loading.gif") url("images/prev.png") url("images/next.png");
  display: none;
}
body.lb-disable-scrolling {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.lightboxOverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: black;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
}
.lightbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.lightbox .lb-image {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
  max-height: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* Image border */
  border: 4px solid white;
}
.lightbox a img {
  border: none;
}
.lb-outerContainer {
  position: relative;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* Background color behind image.
     This is visible during transitions. */
  background-color: white;
}
.lb-outerContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.lb-loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  left: 0;
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
}
.lb-cancel {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url("images/loading.gif") no-repeat;
}
.lb-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.lb-container > .nav {
  left: 0;
}
.lb-nav a {
  outline: none;
  background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==');
}
.lb-prev, .lb-next {
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
.lb-nav a.lb-prev {
  width: 34%;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  background: url("images/prev.png") left 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}
.lb-nav a.lb-prev:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
.lb-nav a.lb-next {
  width: 64%;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  background: url("images/next.png") right 48% no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
}
.lb-nav a.lb-next:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
.lb-dataContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  *zoom: 1;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.lb-dataContainer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.lb-data {
  padding: 0 4px;
  color: #ccc;
}
.lb-data .lb-details {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}
.lb-data .lb-caption {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.lb-data .lb-caption a {
  color: #4ae;
}
.lb-data .lb-number {
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #999999;
}
.lb-data .lb-close {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url("images/close.png") top right no-repeat;
  text-align: right;
  outline: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
.lb-data .lb-close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Why you are loading scripts in head? Try moving every JS script to the bottom of the page, right before `</body>` closing tag

Comment: most likely the file path is incorrect.

Comment: Path is correct I think. I checked it. Sebastian Kaczmarek any errors but just I saw warning in data-lightbox, description: Attribute data-lightbox is not allowed here.
This inspection highlights unknown HTML tag attributes as invalid, and lets mark such attributes as Custom to avoid highlightinh them as invalid.Hm. How fix this warning?

Comment: did you include the icon directory from the dist? If so, make sure you did not move it into a different directory.

Comment: I took this icons from dist but I don't have dist in my own project. This is wrong? I think it's doesn't matter but I will check it evening.

Comment: I checked and nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. 
`<link href="lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">` is wrong.
Should be:

```
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Uff. Now is correct!

Comment: And it's correct when I have 3 files: js with lightbox.ja, css with lightbox.css and images with icons.